# Memory Consumption for React.memo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, stack-navigator, memo

Just want to know how memo works for different screens? Like if I have different screens in my app how much memory will it consume? And if I am using a Stack Navigator will the memorization work until my app is open for all the screens in Stack even my components are very heavy?